# Statement Error ORA-00923

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00923

i have a database that I have populated.

I am now trying to write a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT + FULL ( fst) full(fs) COUNT(DISTINCT r1.CLIENT_ID || e.CODE || fst.TAB_ID) NB_TAB FROM RATTACHEMENT_DART rd, FLUX_SORTANT fs, FS_TABLEAU fst, equipement e, REFERENTIEL r1, referentiel r2, referentiel pere;
```

When I try to run the above case statement I recieve the following error:

> Erreur commençant à la ligne 4 de la commande : SELECT + FULL ( fst)
>   full(fs) COUNT(DISTINCT r1.CLIENT_ID || e.CODE || fst.TAB_ID) NB_TAB
>   FROM RATTACHEMENT_DART rd, FLUX_SORTANT fs, FS_TABLEAU fst, equipement
>   e, REFERENTIEL r1, referentiel r2, referentiel pere Erreur à la ligne
>   de commande : 4, colonne : 26 Rapport d'erreur : Erreur SQL :
>   ORA-00923: mot-clé FROM absent à l'emplacement prévu
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use hints you should use `/*+...*/` as below

```
SELECT /*+ FULL( fst) full(fs)*/ COUNT(DISTINCT r1.CLIENT_ID || e.CODE || fst.TAB_ID) NB_TAB 
FROM RATTACHEMENT_DART rd, FLUX_SORTANT fs, 
     FS_TABLEAU fst, equipement e, 
     REFERENTIEL r1, referentiel r2, referentiel pere;
```

**[See documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/hintsref.htm#5078)**